# How do I write a TypeScript declaration file for an external commonjs module that has constructor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, declaration, commonjs

PLEASE SEE MORE DETAILED QUESTION: [How do I write a TypeScript declaration file for a complex external commonjs module that has constructor, such as imap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249210/how-do-i-write-a-typescript-declaration-file-for-a-complex-external-commonjs-mod)

I write TypeScript for a Node.js app, and I want to write a TypeScript declaration file for a javascript module (available from npm) that has a constructor at the module level.

Here is a simplified version of the relevant code, in file **a.js**:

```
function A(config) {
    this.state = 'constructed';
}
A.prototype.update = function() {
    this.state = 'updated';
};
module.exports = A;
```

and a simplified javascript application, **app.js**, that uses module **a**:

```
var mod = require('a');
var i = new mod({});
console.log('i.state=' + i.state);
i.update();
console.log('i.state=' + i.state);
```

How do I write a TypeScript declaration file for module **a.js**?

I've read the [TypeScript Guide for Writing Definition (.d.ts) Files](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files)
but unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to apply the guidelines to this case.

---

### updated to include interfaces

Here is my declaration file **a.d.ts**:

```
declare module 'a' {
    import events                           = require('events');
    import EventEmitter                     = events.EventEmitter;

    interface Config {
        foo: number;
    }
    interface Other {
        baz: number;
    }

    class A extends EventEmitter {
        state: string;
        constructor(config: Config);
        update(): void;
    }

    var out: typeof A;
    export = out;
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the interfaces available to my TypeScript app. 
I also want to keep them within the module, so that names like Config don't collide with those from other modules.

---

### Added TypeScript app that uses this declaration

This is what I expect my **app.ts** to look like:

```
import mod = require('a');
import Config = mod.Config;
import Other = mod.Other;

var other : Other = {a: 2};
var config : Config = {foo: 2};
var i = new mod(config);
console.log('i.state=' + i.state)
i.update();
console.log('i.state=' + i.state)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to do this, here is one:

```
declare class A {
    state: string;
    constructor(config: any);
    update(): void;
}

declare module 'a' {
    var out: typeof A;

    export = out;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to include interfaces, but also have an exported class, you can set it up like this:

```
declare module A {
    class A {
        state: string;
        constructor();
        update(): void;
    }

    interface B {
        value: any;
    }
}

declare module 'a' {
    var out: typeof A.A;

    export = out;
}
```

Comment: I also tried moving the class declaration inside of the module (without the declare keyword), and that worked too.

Comment: I have a complication: How can I also define public interfaces in module **a**? It seems that the **export =** statment prevents this.

Comment: I can't get the answer with interfaces to work. I've added a typescript app.ts to the question. BTW, the compiler issues misleading error text in this case: "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'mod'.", when it cannot find Config or Other.

Comment: Thanks. This led me on the right path. I found another module, auth0, similar to the one I want to declare, and worked from the patterns there. Those patterns are similar to the ones you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I found an existing declaration file for a modules that has similar structure to the one for which I want to write a declaration file: auth0

- [auth0 on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/auth0)
- [auth0.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/auth0/auth0.d.ts)

I now have something that works, although not yet ideal.
The declaration file **a.d.ts** is:

```
/// <reference path='node.d.ts' />
interface Config {
    foo: number;
}

declare module 'a' {
    import events                           = require('events');
    import EventEmitter                     = events.EventEmitter;

    class A extends EventEmitter {
        constructor(config : Config);
        state: string;
        update(): void;
    }
    var out: typeof A;
    export = out;
}
```

with the TypeScript app file **app.ts** being:

```
/// <reference path='a.d.ts' />
import mod = require('a');

var config : Config = {
    foo: 1
} 
var i = new mod(config);
console.log('i.state=' + i.state)
i.update();
console.log('i.state=' + i.state)
```

and the **a.js** module being as in the original question.

I compile this with: `tsc --module commonjs app.ts`

This certainly works for now.

Although I think it's messy to have the interface (Config) outside of the module, but I haven't yet figured out how to move the interfaces inside.